# Disable/Cancel Sleep Command on MacOSX

Tags: macos, applescript, sleep, osx-leopard

It seems to be impossible to completely disable the Sleep option in MacOSX so that a user cannot manually put the system to sleep.

Is there a way in Leopard (or even Snow Leopard) for AppleScript to catch the Sleep event and cancel it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't do this from user mode, because the power manager prevents it, so you'll need to use a kernel extension, such as [InsomniaX](http://semaja2.net/insomniaxinfo).

Answer (score 5):

The answer to your problem is however a simple Apple-osx-Terminal command that prevents OSX to go idle:

```
$ pmset noidle
Preventing idle sleep (^C to exit)...
```

The only way to reset the no-sleeping is to issue a 'Control-C'.

See the **man** pages of pmset for more details.

This command has been deprecated in favor for

```
$ caffeinate -i
```

Which does roughly the same. 
You can also run caffeinate for a pre-determined amount of time to prevent sleeping, say for 4 hours while you download something, and then run it in the background by adding & to it:

```
$ caffeinate -t 144000 &
```

Answer (score 0):

Newer version(s) of OSX make it more possible to disable certain options according to https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/35256/mac-os-x-lion-server-how-to-disable-sleep-restart-shutdown-options-for-users